# Why can't I completely remove any applications?

Tags: 11.04, synaptic

I am trying to completely remove some of the applications, using Synaptic Package Manager, that I have uninstalled in Ubuntu 11.04. I'm pretty sure I am doing everything correctly. I check the application as "mark for complete removal," but the Apply button stays unclickbable. I also tried 'sudo apt-get purge (application)', and that isn't doing it either. Is this a bug or what?

Comment: what does using 'apt-get purge' report?

Comment: did you try `sudo aptitude remove --purge <package>`?

Comment: @thomas micheal wallace It says 

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kmetronome*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

But the application is still in the "residual config" section of Synaptic. Is this just a bug?

@EvilPheonix Yep.

Comment: I have the same problem, and filed a "Bug" for it a couple of weeks ago. Haven't heard anything back about it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has just worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg --purge [package name]
```

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you! It's been driving me insane lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove <package_name>
```

This command removes an installed package, leaving configuration files intact.

```
sudo apt-get purge <package_name>
```

This command completely removes a package and the associated configuration files. Configuration files residing in ~ are not usually affected by this command.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command removes packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed.

Comment: I tried those but in Synaptic all my uninstalled applications are still in the residual config section. It only started doing that recently. They usually all disappear when I use those commands. Do you think maybe it's just a bug?